# Left continuity of a process, example

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes

Let X be a bounded $\mathcal F_s-$measurable random variable. Let $s < t$.
How can I see that the process $$\big(X\mathbb1_{(s,t]}(u)\big)_{u\ge0}$$ is left-continuous?

Comment: Well, what does it mean for a process to be left-continuous? Does your process have that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A left-continuous process $\ (Y_{u})_{u\ge 0} \ $ is such a process, that almost all its trajectories are left-continuous functions.

More formally:

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg( \Big\{\omega \in \Omega :  \  \ \mathbb{R}_{+}\ni u  \ \ \longmapsto \ Y_{u}(\omega) \ \ \  \text{is left-contionous} \ \Big \} \Bigg) =1. \  $$

Fix $\ \omega \in \Omega. \ $In our case, hence $\ X \ $ is bounded,  $\ X(\omega)\ $ is equal to some finite  value $\ a\in \mathbb{R} \ $ and 
$$\mathbb{R}_{+} \ni u \longmapsto a \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(s,t]}(u) $$
is obviously left-continuous function.

Lastly note, that  $\ X \ $ being $\ \mathcal{F}_{s} \ $ measurable makes the whole process $\Big(X \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(s,t]}(u)\Big)_{u\ge 0}$ adapted to given filtration $\ (\mathcal{F}_{u})_{u\ge 0}$.

Comment: $1)$ So it is not right continuous because if i take a limit towards $s$ the function take value $=0$ instead that $a$ right? $2)$ why the process it is $\mathcal F_u$ measurable and not $\mathcal F_s$?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) We do not say that process $(Y_{u})_{u \ge 0}$ is measurable, rather that it is adapted to some filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{u})_{u \ge 0}$, i.e. for every fixed $u$, the random variable $Y_{u}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{u}$ measurable.

Comment: okey but it seems to me that for every fixed u $\Big(X \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(s,t]}(u)\Big)_{u\ge 0}$ is $\mathcal F_s$ measurable. why instead it is $\mathcal F_u$ measurable for every fixed u

Comment: Filtration always satisfies  $\mathcal{F}_{a}\subset \mathcal{F}_{b}$ for $a \le b$. Hence if  $Y_{u}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ measurable,  then it must be also $\mathcal{F}_{u}$ mensurable for all $u \ge s$. For $u\le s$ our $Y_{u}$ is simply constant $0$ and hence is mensurable with respect to any  $\sigma$-field, $\mathcal{F}_{u}$ among others.

Comment: it is not clear to me your last sentence: if $Y_u$ is $\mathcal F_s$ measurable, then it must be also $\mathcal F_u$ mensurable for all ≥

Comment: $Y_{u}$ being $\mathcal{F_{s}}$ measurable means, that for any Borel set $B$ we have $Y_{u}^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F_{s}}$ (this is definition). But from definition of filtration, one have $\mathcal{F}_{s}\subset \mathcal{F}_{u}$ for any $u\ge s$. Hence $Y_{u}^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F_{s}} \implies Y_{u}^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F_{u}}.$